# Как можно увеличить скорость программы?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код в самом внизу.

У меня есть матрица размером `n x m`. В ней нужно найти подматрицу наибольшей площади состоящих из отрицательных чисел.
Программа выводит координаты верхнего левого угла подматрицы и правого нижнего угла подматрицы.
Например, у меня матрица

```
 1 -9 -2   8   6  1
 8 -1 -11 -7   6  4
10 12 -1  -9 -12 14
 8 10 -3  -5  17  8
 6  4 10 -13 -16 19
```

и вывод

```
1 2
3 3
```

Код работает, но для матриц гигантских размеров, код работает слишком медленно. Хотелось бы, чтобы программа считала за `O(n*log(n))` или `O(n^2)` (n - это количество элементов в матрице.

```
def check_matrix(matrix, i0, j0, size_x, size_y):
    for j in range(j0, j0 + size_y):
        for i in range(i0, i0 + size_x):
            if matrix[j][i] >= 0:
                return False
    return True



def main():
    f = open("matrix.txt", "r")
    matrix=[]
    for line in f:
        matrix.append(list(map(int, line.split())))

    size_max, data = 0, (-1, -1, 0, 0)

    for j in range(len(matrix)-1):
        for i in range(len(matrix[j])-1):
            if matrix[j][i] < 0:
                for size_y in range(1, len(matrix) - j):
                    for size_x in range(1, len(matrix[j]) - i):
                        if check_matrix(matrix, i, j, size_x, size_y):
                            if size_max < size_x * size_y:
                                size_max = size_x * size_y
                                data = j, i, i+size_x-1,j+size_y-1

    print(data[0], data[1])
    print(data[2], data[3])

main()
```

Comment: Объясните, как вы получили желаемый ответ, если ваша подматрица должна состоять из отрицательных чисел, и в то-же время подматрица с диагональными координатами (1,2) и (3,3)  содержит число 12 (с координатой 3,2)?

Comment: 1,2 это значит по индексу 1 ряд и по индексу второй столбец. Нормальным языком это 2 ряд и 3 столбец. (3,3) это 4 ряд и 4 столбец. Подматрица не обязательно должна быть квадратной

Comment: не надо фантазировать. Открываем Википедию и читаем "Ма́трица — математический объект, записываемый в виде ПРЯМОУГОЛЬНОЙ таблиц".  Напоминаю -  квадрат -  частный случай прямоугольника. Если вы выдумываете свою трактовку термина, то хотя-бы проинформируйте об этом окружающих. Иначе ваш вопрос и пример выглядит по меньшей мере противоречащими друг другу.

Comment: @passant, всё у него нормально, только в 0-индексации посчитай, а не в 1-индексации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод с линейным временем O(nm), требует использования непростого в понимании субалгоритма.

Заводим новую матрицу, или, если не жалко, работаем внутри имеющейся. Обходим матрицу по строкам, положительные числа заменяем на 0, отрицательные на 1+значение в верхней ячейке. Таким образом, в каждой ячейке получаем **высоту столбика от текущей ячейки до верхнего нуля**.

А для задачи нахождения максимальной площади под столбиками ("под гистограммой")

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть хитрый алгоритм на основе (мотононного) стека.

Применив его к каждой строке матрицы, получим максимальную площадь.

Полный код с площадью и позицией:

```
A = [[ 1, -9, -2,   8,   6 , 1],
     [8, -1, -11, -7,   6,  4],
     [10, 12, -1,  -9, -12, 14],
     [8, 10, -3,  -5,  17,  8],
     [6,  4, 10, -13, -16, 19]]

def maxAreaInHist(arr):
    best = 0
    bstart = 0
    blen = 0
    bhgt = 0
    stack = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        while (len(stack) > 0) and (arr[stack[-1]] >= arr[i]):
        #нашли меньший столбик, удаляем все бОльшие
            smallest = arr[stack.pop()]
            if len(stack) == 0:
                start = 0
            else:
                start = stack[-1]+ 1
            #range_length * smallest_weight_in_range
            ar = smallest * (i - start)
            if ar > best:
                best = ar
                bstart = start
                blen = i - start
                bhgt = smallest
        stack.append(i)
    return best, bstart, blen, bhgt

def maxar(A):
    r = len(A)
    c = len(A[0])
    for i in range(c):
        A[0][i] = 1 if A[0][i] < 0 else 0
    for y in range(1, r):
       for i in range(c):
           A[y][i] = 1 + A[y-1][i] if A[y][i] < 0 else 0
    maxarea = 0
    for y in range(r):
        best, bstart, blen, bhgt = maxAreaInHist(A[y])
        if best > maxarea:
            maxarea = best
            y0, x0, y1, x1 = y - bhgt + 1, bstart, y, bstart + blen - 1
    print(maxarea, y0, x0, y1, x1)

maxar(A)

>>6 1 2 3 3
```

Comment: Во-первых, я не вижу причин, почему `maxAreaInHist` работает за `O(len(a))`, а без этого общее `O(n*m)` не сойдётся. Во-вторых, зачем вообще стек - почему бы не заменить его на минимум?

Comment: @Qwertiy Работает за линейное время, потому что каждый элемент добавляется и снимается со стека не более, чем один раз, и общее количество проверок ифа ограничено длиной массива. Про минимум - на картинке как раз пример, что лучший результат получился не с минимумом.

Answer (score 2):

Код в вопросе работает за `O((n*m)**3)`. Могу предложить простое решение за `O((n*m)**2)`:

1. Составляем матрицу того же размера с 1 в ячейке, если соответствующее число отрицательно и 0 если нет.
2. Эту матрицу пересчитываем в матрицу частичных сумм (в принципе, можно сделать сразу на первом шаге).
3. Теперь чтобы проверить, что матрица заданная углами l,t,r,b содержит только отрицательные числа, достаточно проверить, что сумма по ней равна её площади. Cумма считается в два вычитания и сложение примерно так: `s[b,r] - s[b,l] - s[t,r] + s[t,l]`, тольно надо подогнать сдвиги на 1 в зависимости от того, считаются границы включительно или нет и есть ли защитная рамка для предотвращения выхода за пределы матрицы.

Насчёт потенциальных дальнейших оптимизаций: модно попытаться применить метод сканирующей прямой и сближения left и right за счёт увеличения bottom при фиксированном top. Но я не очень понимаю, как это применить.

Answer (score 1):

можно вот так оптимизировать:

основная идея - мы сразу проверяем подматрицу на неотрицательные числа и если такие числа в подматрице попадаются, мы перестаём рассматривать подматрицы большего размера

данный подход также позволяет избавиться от функции `check_matrix`

```
size_max, data = 0, (-1, -1, 0, 0)

for j in range(len(matrix) - 1):
    for i in range(len(matrix[j]) - 1):
        if matrix[j][i] < 0:
            for size_y in range(1, len(matrix) - j):
                if matrix[j + size_y][i] >= 0:
                    break

                for size_x in range(1, len(matrix[j]) - i):

                    if matrix[j + size_y][i + size_x] >= 0:
                        break

                    square = size_x * size_y

                    if size_max < square:
                        size_max = square
                        data = i, j, j + size_x, size_y

print(data[1], data[0])
print(data[2], data[3])
```

проверял на случайной матрице 1000x1000

Еще в несколько раз можно ускорить, если минимальный размер подматрицы (длину) выбирать исходя из максимальной площади:

```
for j in range(len(matrix) - 1):
    for i in range(len(matrix[j]) - 1):
        for size_y in range(1, len(matrix) - j):
            if matrix[j + size_y][i] >= 0:
                break

            for size_x in range(size_max // size_y, len(matrix[j]) - i): # оптимизация тут

                if matrix[j + size_y][i + size_x] >= 0:
                    break

                square = size_x * size_y

                if size_max < square:
                    size_max = square
                    data = i, j, j + size_x, size_y
```

Comment: На случайной неинтересно.

Comment: ну надо было хоть на чем-то проверять - когда очень большие массивы, то скорость примерно одинаковая и когда ускорение составляет порядки, то значит все сделано правильно :)

хотя в данном алгоритме можно еще улучшить скорость - чтобы не рассматривать подматрицы меньшего размера, чем это нужно и чтобы не рассматривать правый нижний угол меньше по площади, чем найденная подматрица (но там у меня 0,5% прирост только получился, так что он несущественен)

Comment: тут же прикол в том, что он возмет в счет первую попавшуюся подматрицу, но спасибо

Comment: @Khimer, не понял, что именно вы имели в виду?

Comment: ну то что после найденной первой подходящей подматрицы, поиски прекратятся, а может там была еще одна подматрица побольше

Comment: @Zhihar, нет, в случайной матрице будет очень быстро попадаться ложный элемент и ответ будет небольшим. А вот если ты заполнишь всю матрицу отрицательными числами, то ни один break не сработает. Ну и уж чтобы отбить желание проверить такую ситуацию, можно куда-то внутрь влепить одно или два положительных.

Comment: @Khimer, с чего бы они прекратились?

Comment: нет - вы не понял - смотрите, поиски прекратятся по дальнейшей ширине или высоте, а не вообще - раньше вширь проверялось все до края, а теперь до первого неотрицательного числа, потому что дальше нет смысл проверять ибо уже есть неотрицательное

Comment: проверил, все таки берет в счет первую попавшуюся подходящую матрицу, попробуйте проверить даже на обычных матрицах, ответы отличаются

Comment: да, действительно, где-то ошибку допустил